# Can you use line item values in formulas on the Opportunity page?

Tags: formula, opportunity, quotelineitem

I am wondering whether or not it is possible to extract the values of the line items from a quote and use them in formulas on the opportunity page? We're looking to show how much of a potential deal would go to each of our partners for reporting purposes. The division of the revenues from a deal is divided different depending on the line item so I'm wondering if I can work with these values in a formula.

EDIT FOR CLARITY : Each line item total needs to be reported on, and each line item's revenue gets divided among our partners. We need to run reports on our liabilities and the revenues that we expect to see from each opportunities line items.

Comment: Correct me If I am wrong. line items are children of Quote and quote is the child of Opportunity. My guess is we can get a value on to the line Item from the Opportunity, but it may not possible to get the value from the line Item to the Opportunity. So we may need to rely on triggers to get the line Item values to the Opportunity level.

Comment: Rollup summaries can achieve some of what you want. It is not clear exactly what you are going for, however.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box, formula fields can not refer to the values of child SObjects, regardless of whether lookup or master-detail relationships.

Formula fields can refer to parent objects via the lookup or master-detail relationship (you can go up to 5 levels)

In order to get a formula field in Opportunity to exploit values in the child object(s), you'll need to get copies of the field(s) into the Opportunity via a variety of techniques.

- Roll up Summary fields (works across master-detail only)
- Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary package (works across lookup relations) or equivalent AppExchange Rollup Helper package
- Process Builder flows (although you'll have issues with delete and undelete CRUD operations)
- Triggers on the child object

Since your application seems to have a variable number of partners, all of the above won;t really be helpful as your data model won't be extensible.  Keep child fields in children when there are multiple children

If this is a display-only issue and you don't need reports, you can use an embedded Visualforce page within the standard detail page layout that fetches from the child and summarizes the info in the way to aid in decision making